# Time complexity of prim algorithm using fibonacci heap or binary heap when bipartite-graph is given

Tags: algorithm

I want to further know details of prim's time complexity. Basically, the prim's time complexity is `O(V^2)`. When binary heap or fibonacci heap are used, then the time complexity is enhanced to `O(E + V log(V))` or `O(Elog(V))`.

My question is as below.

1. Why some codes are using the basic prim algorithm even the other versions of prim give a better solution? Is there a special reason to use the basic prim algorithm which gives a `O(V^2)`?. Implementation is quite easy compared to advanced prim's version. Otherwise, I assume that there are no special reasons to use the basic prim algorithm.
2. When the bipartite graph is given, can I apply the fibonacci or binary heap prim's version to the bipartitie graph instead of the basic prim version? The existing code that I've analyzed uses basic prim algorithm in the bipartite graph. What I want to do is to make the code speed better. So, I want to change the data structure of the prim using binary or fibonacci heap in order to reduce the execution time. Is is achievable to use the advanced prim versions for the bipartite graph not for the normal graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you implement the algorithm in real life, asymptotic time complexity is not the most important thing: practical efficiency and simplicity also matter.

First, though theoretical complexity of Prim's algorithm with Fibonacci heap is better than that of binary heap (O(E log V) vs O(E + V log V)), Fibonacci heaps are really slow in practice, so your value of E should be really large to notice the difference. I haven't seen any practical example of this. Simple binary (or k-ary, with k being 4 or 8) are very, very fast.

Second, there are dense graphs (where E ~ V^2) and sparse graphs (where E ~ V). (Of course there are intermediate categories, but in general any practical graph can be regarded as sparse or dense). For dense graphs the standard Prim's algorithm with O(V^2) runtime is the best, both theoretically and practically. Maybe this is the reason to use the simpler version. Or maybe performance simply doesn't matter at that point, because graphs are not that big.

Regarding your second question: I haven't heard of any specific algorithms for finding MST in a bipartite graph. Of course you can apply any version of the algorithm, but I doubt there exist any special tricks for bipartite case.

P.S. For sparse graphs consider Kruskal's algorithm. It is O(E log E), but the only heavy part is sorting, which is also very fast today.